# Subclassing tuple with multiple __init__ arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, tuples

The following code works:

```
class Foo(tuple):

    def __init__(self, b):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(tuple(b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print Foo([3, 4])

$ python play.py
```

Result:

```
play.py:4: DeprecationWarning: object.__init__() takes no parameters
  super(Foo, self).__init__(tuple(b))
(3, 4)
```

But not the following:

```
class Foo(tuple):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(tuple(b))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print Foo(None, [3, 4])

$ python play.py
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "play.py", line 7, in <module>
    print Foo(None, [3, 4])
TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Why?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Because tuples are immutable, you have to override `__new__` instead:

[python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> `object.__new__(cls[, ...])`
>
> Called to create a new instance of
>   class `cls`. `__new__()` is a static
>   method (special-cased so you need not
>   declare it as such) that takes the
>   class of which an instance was
>   requested as its first argument. The
>   remaining arguments are those passed
>   to the object constructor expression
>   (the call to the class). The return
>   value of `__new__()` should be the new
>   object instance (usually an instance
>   of `cls`).
>
> Typical implementations create a new
>   instance of the class by invoking the
>   superclass’s `__new__()` method using
>   `super(currentclass, cls).__new__(cls[, ...])` with appropriate arguments and
>   then modifying the newly-created
>   instance as necessary before returning
>   it.
>
> If `__new__()` returns an instance of
>   `cls`, then the new instance’s
>   `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where self is the new instance and the remaining
>   arguments are the same as were passed
>   to `__new__()`.
>
> If `__new__()` does not return an
>   instance of `cls`, then the new
>   instance’s `__init__()` method will not
>   be invoked.
>
> `__new__()` is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like
>   `int`, `str`, or `tuple`) to customize
>   instance creation. It is also commonly
>   overridden in custom metaclasses in
>   order to customize class creation.

Comment: can someone tell me how to quote the whole block so the double underscores don't mean bold?

Comment: Select the whole pasted text and click on the quote icon (black icon on top of the text box).

Comment: I replaced them all with &#95;

Answer (score 64):

To assign the tuple value you need to override the `__new__` method:

```
class Foo(tuple):

    def __new__ (cls, a, b):
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, tuple(b))
```

The arguments seem to be ignored by the `__init__` implementation of the tuple class, but if you need to do some init stuff you can do it as follows:

```
class Foo(tuple):

    def __new__ (cls, a, b):
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, tuple(b))

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(None, [3, 4])
    print foo
    print foo.a
    print foo.b
```