# python: overriding access a var

Tags: python, overriding

I have a class:

```
class A:
    s = 'some string'
    b = <SOME OTHER INSTANCE>
```

now I want this class to have the functionality of a string whenever it can. That is:

```
a = A()
print a.b
```

will print `b`'s value. But I want functions that expect a string (for example `replace`) to work. For example:

```
'aaaa'.replace('a', a)
```

to actually do:

```
'aaa'.replace('a', a.s)
```

I tried overidding `__get__` but this isn't correct.

I see that you can do this by subclassing `str`, but is there a way without it?

Comment: Is there a reason you _don't_ want to inherit from `str`? That would be the right way to do this.

Comment: well, as the title of the question says, it's a more general question. This solution is good but I think overriding "access a var" will come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in [Subclassing Python tuple with multiple __init__ arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-python-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments) .

I used Dave's solution and extended str, and then added a **new** function:

```
def __new__(self,a,b):
    s=a
    return str.__new__(A,s)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want your class to have the functionality of a string, just extend the built in string class.

```
>>> class A(str):
...     b = 'some other value'
...
>>> a = A('x')
>>> a
'x'
>>> a.b
'some other value'
>>> 'aaa'.replace('a',a)
'xxx'
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `__str__` or `__unicode__` to set the string representation of an object ([Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)).

Comment: Then use Dave's solution, that should support the whole string functionality. My solution only works for a small subset.