# Problem subclassing random.Random (python /CPython 2.6)

Tags: python, random, subclass, built-in

I have tried this code snippet in CPython 2.6 (original python implementation):

```
from random import Random, random

class Uniform(Random, object):
    def __init__(self,  min,  max):
        self._min =min
        self._max =max
    def randint(self):
        return super(Uniform, self).randint (self._min,  self._max)
    def uniform(self):
        return super(Uniform, self).uniform(self._min,  self._max)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=Uniform(0.,  1.2)
    print a.uniform()
    print a.randint()
```

Although it seems to be **CORRECT** pythonic inheritance, it throws this error:

```
/tmp/source.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 13   a=Uniform(0.,  1.2)
     14   print a.uniform()
     15   print a.randint()

TypeError: seed expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
WARNING: Failure executing file: </tmp/source.py>
```

But if you define

```
def __init__(self,  min,  max):
```

as

```
def __init__(self,  (min,  max)):
```

things will miraculously go on "correctly".. but the first generated random numbers will be always the same for all instances of Uniform (because of the same initial seed!).

**PROBLEM SOURCE**

The `random.Random` class IS new-style class and definitely it is NOT basic class (see /usr/lib/python2.6/random.py on Unix and its equivalent on Win). So hacks about subclassing of built-in classes -- will be in our course. The `random.Random` class -- despite of its new-style nature subclasses **at first class written in C** (in /usr/lib/python2.6/random.py see `import _random` -and it is *built-in class*!).

What does it mean? We need to override `__new__` method as if it was builtin class itself (more here: [problem subclassing builtin type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827303/problem-subclassing-builtin-type)).

**FINAL WORKAROUND IN SHORT**

Just add overriding of `__new__` method (that `random()` was imported in the 2nd line of this "question" and is just object passed behind the scene to `random.Random.seed(x)` to initialize the object seed (in source of /usr/lib/python2.6/random.py) ).

```
class Uniform(Random, object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super (Uniform, cls).__new__ (cls, random() )
    def __init__(self,  min,  max):
        self._min =min
        self._max =max
```

Enjoy the built-in Mersenne Twister random number generator in Python ;-) Good LUCK!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Random.__init__(self, seed)` at the beginning of your constructor (the `seed` argument is optional):

```
def __init__(self,  min,  max):
    Random.__init__(self)  # Use the default seed.
    self._min =min
    self._max =max
```

Also, I don't quite understand why you are explicitly extending `object` as well; extending `Random` should suffice.