# Creating a Python class that holds its value as an upper case string doesn't work

Tags: python, class, customization

Why doesn't this work?

```
>>> class A (unicode):
...     def __init__ (self, value):
...         super(unicode, self).__init__(str(value).upper())
...
>>> assert A('hello') == u'HELLO'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    assert A('hello') == u'HELLO'
AssertionError
>>>
```

I know that without the **init** method initializing the object would default to the unicode classes **init** method (thank you MRO) and I know that my **init** method is the one being called, however it doesn't seem to want to work.  Even when I add an extra line and explicitly set the value of the value parameter to upper it still doesn't want to work.

Although I can (and probably will have to) define the **repr** and **str** special classes in order to get the desired effect, I'm a little curious as to why this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unicode` are [immutable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-python-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments) use `__new__` instead of `__init__`:

```
class A (unicode):
    def __new__ (cls, value):
       return unicode.__new__(cls, str(value).upper())

print A('hello')
u'HELLO'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `super(unicode, self)`, you probably want `super(A, self)` - the former is `object.__init__`.

Additionally, since unicode objects are immutable, `__init__` does nothing. Instead of the regular initialization with `__init__` (which would also prevent [interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intern_(computer_science))), the constructor you want to override is [`__new__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

```
class A (unicode):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls, str(value).upper())
```

Comment: +1, there's no 'probably' about it.  `super` sure can be confusing.

Comment: @phihag, I can understand the first part, in fact I usually use super(self.__class__, self).  I think I understand the second part... because unicode objects are immutable, the value is actually set when the instance is being created (hence __new__) not after it has been created and is being initialized.  Thanks.