# Why does my Python inheritance/super example not work?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

Why doesn't the following work:

```
class CTest(tuple):
    def __init__(self,arg):
        if type(arg) is tuple:
            super(CTest,self).__init__((2,2))
        else:
            super(CTest,self).__init__(arg)
a=CTest((1,1))
print a
```

The ouput is (1,1), while I expect to see (2,2).

Also, why do I get a deprecation warning that object.**init**() takes no parameters? What should I do instead?

Comment: @PetrAbdulin - From the looks of it, Python.

Comment: Corrected, sorry. It is Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, you have to override `__new__`:

```
class CTest(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        if type(arg) is tuple:
            return super(CTest, cls).__new__(cls, (2, 2))
        else:
            return super(CTest, cls).__new__(cls, arg)
```

Now this works as expected:

```
a = CTest((1,1))
print a
> (2, 2)
```

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565374/201359) for further details.