# How to initialize an instance of a subclass of tuple in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subclassing Python tuple with multiple __init__ arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-python-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments)

I want to define a class which inherits from `tuple`, and I want to be able to instantiate it using a syntax not supported by `tuple`. For a simple example, let's say I want to define a class `MyTuple` which inherits from `tuple`, and which I can instantiate by passing two values, `x` and `y`, to create the (my) tuple `(x, y)`. I've tried the following code:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        print("debug message")
        super().__init__((x, y))
```

But when I tried, for example, `MyTuple(2, 3)` I got an error: `TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`. It seems my `__init__` function was not even called (based on the error I got and on the fact my "debug message" was not printed).

So what's the right way to do this?

I'm using Python 3.2.

Comment: You might want to take a peek at [``collections.namedtuple()``](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: Please check [this original SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-python-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments) for a thorough answer on (1) why you need to use `__new__` instead of `__init__` (2) what other steps  you need to follow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (x, y))

x = MyTuple(2,3)
print(x)
# (2, 3)
```

One of the difficulties of using `super` is that you do not control which classes's method of the same name is going to be called next. So all the classes' methods have to share the same call signature -- at least the same number of items. Since you are changing the number of arguments sent to `__new__`, you can not use `super`.

---

Or as Lattyware suggests, you could define a namedtuple,

```
import collections
MyTuple = collections.namedtuple('MyTuple', 'x y')

p = MyTuple(2,3)
print(p)
# MyTuple(x=2, y=3)
print(p.x)
# 2
```

Comment: You could use `*tuple` (or `*args`) rather than `x,y`, then it would generalise to arbitrary size.

Answer (score 1):

another approach would be to encapsulate a tuple rather than inheriting from it:

```
>>> class MyTuple(object):
    count = lambda self, *args: self._tuple.count(*args)
    index = lambda self, *args: self._tuple.index(*args)
    __repr__ = lambda self: self._tuple.__repr__()
    # wrap other methods you need, or define them yourself,
    # or simply forward all unknown method lookups to _tuple
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._tuple = x,y


>>> x = MyTuple(2,3)
>>> x
(2, 3)
>>> x.index(3)
1
```

How practical this is, depends on how many capabilities and modifications you need, and wheter you need to have `isinstance(MyTuple(2, 3), tuple)`.

Comment: Interesting. Took me some time to understand what looks like field assignments and the lambdas. Any particular reason why you didn't use the normal `def` construction? Also, how do you "forward all unknown method lookups to `_tuple`"?

Comment: no particular reason for the lambdas, I just like to "bind" functions like that. `count = lambda:...` says to me "count IS ASSIGNED TO BE the count of _tuple".

Comment: You can forward unknown method lookups with `def __getattr__(self, attr):
  return self._tuple.__getattribute__(attr)`

Comment: @ch3ka your forward unknown method lookups works well with the old-style class not the new-style class. For new-style class, magic methods,  such as `__iter__`, `__contains__`, must be defined or `AttributeError` will be raised. New-style class makes these magic methods as class's attributes, search only in that class and not call `__getattr__()`