# Writing a wrapper for Python's tuple class

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a wrapper for Python's tuple class, just so I can have an object that behaves like a tuple, but just has a couple of attributes and an extra function or two. I can't seem to resolve the conflict of constructors and inheritance though. This is what I want for the constructor:

```
class Edge(tuple):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(self, (x, y))
        self.head, self.tail = x, y
```

Thus, `Edge(1,2)` would form the tuple `(1, 2)` with attributes `x` and `y`. And if it's possible, I'd like to even disallow the tuple's other constructors (`tuple()` and `tuple(iter)`), but that isn't a priority.

No matter how I write the code, however, it always seems like tuple's constructors take precidence over mine, thus the error: `TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`.

I'm using Python 3, which I believe makes a difference in the `super()` syntax (I think Python 2 would require something like `super(Edge, self).__init__()`).

Edit: For future readers, I solved this with -

```
class Edge(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        return super().__new__(cls, (x, y))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.head, self.tail = x, y

Edge(1, 2)
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565374/2003420

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple `tuple`'s constructor takes exactly one argument, an iterable

Comment: You may want to look at [`collections.namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead; `Edge = namedtuple('Edge', 'head tail')`, then `Edge(1, 2)` to create an instance. It'll have `head` and `tail` attributes.